# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps.Contract

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to publish a .NET Core (3.1) Web Application for the first time in Visual Studio 2019 and I get the error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps.Contract, Version=15.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps.Contract, Version=15.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps.Contract, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps.Contract, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.FetchContinuousDeliveryService()
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.InitializeContinuousDelivery()
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel..ctor(IThreadSwitcher threadSwitcher, IPublishServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy, ITelemetryProvider telemetryProvider, IVsWrappersFactory vsWrappersFactory, IReadOnlyList`1 providers, IFeatureManager featureDetectionManager, IProfileController profileController, IDependenciesManagerProvider dependenciesManagerProvider)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.PublishProjectDesignerTabProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

The publish window seems to not be fully drawn out in VS 2019 afterward. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to this issue and I'm posting it here. I reinstalled VS2019. I may have missed installing key components during original installation, such as Azure, I'm uncertain on that detail.